# Fantasy novel. Main character called Liddie(?) travels through portals called kuah(?) to alien planets

Tags: story-identification

This novel was about a girl called Liddie(?) or something similar. She lives in a world with many lands, I think about seven, and portals called 'kuah' or something to go to one place or another. I think someone tried to use her and her seven-twelve brothers (I don't remember) for experiments to stabilise the portals, so she tries to save them.

She was thrown into a planet which hardly anyone knows about. There are like three different kinds of species living there, I think. One is like a monkey. The guy that she first meets resembles a human the most. The guy has a monkey species companion that hates a alot. The rest of it's kind do as well. If I remember correctly, it's because that planet had a tough history with the rest of the seven planets. Liddie first lands in a grass patch somewhere in the land but passes out. She thinks of possible planets she could have landed in but could think of none as the planet had two moons, one sliverish and redish which the planets she knows of dosent have that trait.  She learns to write their language as she can't speak because of an implant in her throat that will kill her brothers if she speaks. The person who placed the implant is a person that used to be quite close to Liddie. In that world, there is a game somewhat related to soccer and Liddie participates in it in a part of the story. Liddie's family are made of geniuses and she is the only child of her parents that people think will never live up to the family's title. However it's because she is under stress and can actually do amazing things with if she is in a state of free mind. For some reason I forgot the guy dosent trust her anymore at one point because of a misunderstanding and she escapes with the thrid kind which is very muscular and buff in appearance.

Liddie is very good with tinkering with objects. In the end I think everyone survived except one of her brothers. She gets together with the guy she first meets in the new planet.

If I'm not wrong, I read this around mid year last year. I think it was a book that was a remake of the seven swans(children book) or something. I do not have any memory of the cover. But seeing it's theme I'm sure there is dark blue on the cover. There are random flashbacks placed between each chapter.

Comment: Hello Anya, welcome to the SF and Fantasy Stack, and thank you for your question. As @Valorum has mentioned already, the best way to go about this is asking one identification request per question. That way, it's clearer if the question has been answered. Also, try to add as much information as you can remember about each book, as unimportant as it may seem. Lastly, try to format your question and refrain from txt spk such as "pls", to make it more readable.

Comment: A more descriptive title will attract more interest. Also, how sure are you about the names you've given - kuah and Liddie?

Comment: Also, have a look at the tips on [this tag info page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info), and the FAQ it links to. For instance, when did you read it, when do you think it was written, do you remember anything about the cover, etc.